# 2000 Celica engine dies or shakes when I pump gas

Tags: toyota, fuel-system, automatic-transmission, celica

I have a 2000 Toyota Celica. At first it used to slip gears and then I had a mechanic check it out. He said its a solenoid in the transmission which he changed.

The car sputters sometimes when at top speeds or on the highway.  It acts like it doesn't want to move well or sometimes kicks in. When I buy fuel at the station it just shakes and the engine dies. Please, what could be wrong with my car?

Comment: First, you shouldn't be pumping gas with your engine on, but I think that the car sitting at idle for an extended period probably has more to do with the engine dying than the actual act of pumping gas.  Is the check engine light on?

Comment: @JPhi1618 It's also possible that the ECU is trying to compensate for the fuel system pressure change due to the pump being inserted...

Comment: Welcome to the site. [Could you get us the fuel trims?](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/1470/675) They're key to helping us understand what's going on. If your car can read it fuel pressure as well that would be great. Thanks

Comment: There's always the possibility that you're stirring up sediment on the bottom of the fuel tank, and that's entering the fuel line.

Answer (score 1):

The stalling at high speed could be a variety and/or combination of things: clogged fuel filter, dying fuel pump, collapsing rubber fuel line.  The need for a high fuel flow (engine demand) can cause old rubber fuel lines to collapse (Bernoulli effect). Fuel pump or fuel filter are self-explanatory.

The Celica is fuel injected.  If you uncap your gas tank with the engine running, that will affect fuel flow and make your engine stall.  That's also an unsafe action: unsafe for you and everybody at the station.

Comment: How does it affect fuel flow? It's a submerged electric pump.

Comment: By "it" I assume you're talking about the gas cap. You have a point there,  but I wouldn't totally rule it out. Stranger things have happened. There may be some interlock that shuts down the pump.  In any case, having an open gas cap with the engine running is a questionable practice.